# How can I fix this error regarding no symbol file loaded?

Tags: c++, sdl

I keep having this weird error pop up whenever I try to load in the audio mixer. I'm still very new to SDL and I've tried a multitude of debugging strategies but here's the code and the error will be at the end:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1000;

Mix_Chunk* goku = NULL;

int SDL_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    if (Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL_mixer could not initialize! SDL_mixer Error: %s\n", Mix_GetError());
    }
    goku = Mix_LoadWAV("goku.wav");
    Mix_PlayChannel(-1, goku, 0);
    SDL_Delay(5000);
    Mix_FreeChunk(goku);
    goku = NULL;
   
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;
    Mix_Quit();
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

The Error:

No symbol file loaded for SDL2.dll

`Unhandled exception at 0x7B58290E (SDL2.dll) in TheScorchGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xBE800008.`

I tried reloading the symbols of the loaded dlls since it said no symbol file was found. I've reinstalled SDL twice now and taken every line in and out to try to make it work and it seems like the Mix_OpenAudio is the problem. However I can't seem to find what's wrong with it...

Comment: The error is that you have a crash in your program, not that debug symbols can't be found. I assume you're seeing the debug symbol message in the debugger when the program crashes. Look at the call stack to find the line in your code causing the problem.  My guess would be that `Mix_LoadWAV` fails due to the working directory not being where you think it is, and `goku` is `NULL` here `Mix_PlayChannel(-1, goku, 0);` causing the crash. Try using a full path to the wav file.

Comment: Debug symbols are there to aid in debugging inside the dll and see the variables and functions inside the dll. This is something that you very likely don't need so it's unimportant and its also not the cause of any crash.

Comment: When the program raises this access violation you should look up the stack to see which bit of *your* code made it crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently getting a very similar error. The exception occurs when I call `SDL_CreateWindow()`, but only after I call `Mix_OpenAudio()`. Unfortunately, the only way I've found to fix it is to downgrade to an older version of SDL.